# Finding all combinations of L-R in a String to traverse a datastrucure

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

I want to create all possible variations to traverse a data structure. When I traverse i can either go left (L) or right (R). So my plan for this is to genereate all possible paths, before I traverse the data structure. Each character should serve as an instruction for traversing.

I need a method to generate the following:

```
private List<String> createPaths(int len){
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
            // no clue how to generate them
            return result;
     }
```

for len = 1 the results should be:
{L,R}

for len = 2 the results should be:
{LL,LR,RR,RL}

for len = 3 the results should be:
{LLL,LLR,LRL,LRR,RLL,RLR,RRL,RRR}

I have already tried to solve it with the help of the binary numbers, but I failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tip to use binary numbers actually seems workable to me.  We can generate a collection of fixed width *and* zero padded binary numbers between 0 and some power of 2.  Then, replace all zeroes with `L` and all ones with `R`.

```
private List<String> createPaths(int len) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    String formatWidth = "%" + len + "s";

    for (int i=0; i < Math.pow(2, len); ++i) {
         String val = String.format(formatWidth, Integer.toBinaryString(i))
             .replace(' ', '0')
             .replace("0", "L")
             .replace("1", "R");
         result.add(val);
    }

    return result;
}

System.out.println(createPaths(3));
```

This prints:

```
[LLL, LLR, LRL, LRR, RLL, RLR, RRL, RRR]
```

Comment: Hey cool. I wonder why i spent so many hours yesterday and you only took a few minutes. Thanks a lot. Now I must understand your solution.

Comment: @StimpsonCat I spend too much on this site.  One side effect is I can answer Java and SQL questions quickly.

Comment: Change `Math.pow(2, len)` to `(1 << len)`. --- Change `"%" + len + "s"` to `"%0" + len + "s"` and remove `.replace(' ', '0')`.

Answer (score 3):

"binary numbers" are a very good approach.
So first think of your paths as binary numbers.
So for `len=3` you get all binary numbers of length 3.

These are the numbers 0 to 7 (in decimal). *(= 2^3 = 8 numbers)*

So write a loop to count from `0 to (2^len -1)`
Than simply take the number translate it to binary representation and replace 0 by R and 1 by L (all leading 0s to get always a binary representation of length `len`)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not sure if, this will generate the correct results. I have tried this. The problem are the leading zeroes

Comment: @Stimpson Cat: you can also go without leading zeros and ant the end add `R`s at the left until the length is alright

Comment: Do you know the moment when the coin drops and you feel like a coward, because you did not see the simple solution all the time?. It is a mix of sadness and joy at the same time. Thanks for helping me MrSmith42.